# grep using variable to find multiple output

Tags: linux, bash, variables, grep

I am working on a script to find if ANY IP address that is used is in one of my ban files.

I can get it to work up to storing the variable, but I cannot get the last grep to work using the variable. The reason for the step1 and 2 variables was an attempt to make egrep work.

I am limited with the server I am using. I cannot add anything to it but the base grep, so the fgrep option someone else has shown in another answer does not work.

```
now=$(date +"%Y%m%d"'.log')  
VAR1="/LOCATION1/$now"  
VAR2="/LOCATION2/$now"  
echo Please enter the Username:  
read input  
echo You have entered $input  
read -n 1 -s -r -p "Press any key to continue"  
echo  
echo DETECTED LOGINS FROM THE FOLLOWING IP ADDRESSES:  
all=$(grep "$input" $VAR1 | grep login | grep -E -o "([0-9]{1,3}[.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}" |
      grep -v <MyIP> | sort | uniq &&
      grep "$input" $VAR2 | grep login | grep -E -o "([0-9]{1,3}[.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}" |
      grep -v <MyIP> | sort | uniq)  
echo "${all[*]}"  
echo  
step1=$(echo $all|tr ' ' '|')  
step2=$(echo "'$step1'")  
read -n 1 -s -r -p "Press any key to continue"  
echo  
echo FOUND BANS:  
egrep $step2 /BANLOCATOIN/$now  
read -n 1 -s -r -p "Press any key to end"  
echo
```

Comment: *"the fgrep option [...] does not work"*. If you mean that `fgrep` is not a valid command on your system then try `grep -F` instead.

Comment: can you share few lines as example? `grep, egrep` ,etc. is all that you should need.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that `fgrep` is the same as `grep -F`. I cannot give you an answer at the moment as your question is not clear enough. For instance, what are the IP addresses that are *used*? What exactly goes wrong with the last grep? What is "*the fgrep option [...] shown in another answer*"? Once you edited your question to make it more clear I would be glad to help out.¶ By the way, `all` is not an array, so `${all[*]}` should be the same as `$all`. You may also want to establish the habit of quoting variables. Take a look at https://www.shellcheck.net/ for further improvements.